# Safest way to read a string and store as int in a struct

Tags: c, struct, c89, ansi-c

I am using ANSI C on the gcc compiler (with -ansi).

I need to read user input for the month, day, hour and minute into a struct and they:

- cannot be of datatypes that are not an int,
- each need to conform to individual criteria (`i.e. month > 0 && month <
  13` etc.)

**Struct definition**

```
typedef struct 
    {
      int month;
      int day;
      int hour;
      int minute;
    } date_time_t;

date_time_t departure_date[50];
```

**Typechecking with String Conversion**

I want to check the user input to stop the program crashing if they provide a "~" to the `scanf("%i", departure_date->month);`

So I am reading the value as a string first like this:

```
char temp_month[3]
char *ptr;
scanf("%s", temp_month)
```

And then typechecking the user input  like this:

*while input does not meet criteria -> ask for input that meets criteria*

```
 while(strtol(temp_month,  &ptr, 36) <  1 ||
        strtol(temp_month,  &ptr, 36) > 12) 
    {

  printf("Invalid selection - try again\n");
    scanf(" %s", temp_month);
  }
```

Once the while condition is satisfied, I store the temporary variable inside the struct:

`departure_date->month = atoi(temp_month);`

A couple of questions...

1. Is this a normal way of doing things? Bearing in mind that I am constrained to the struct have only int datatypes.
2. When I submit the keystroke 'a, b, c or d' to the month during the scanf, it passes the criteria set out by the while loop where I am typechecking, but no other letters in the alphabet do that - does anyone know why?

Comment: You could do with reading the manual page for `scanf` - 1. It returns a value 2. You can use the format parameter to ensure that the character arrays are not overrun.

Comment: Apologies I do not understand, can you show me an example?

Comment: `if (scanf("%2s", temp_month) == 1) ....` is something that you require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef int error;
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE 1

error readdate(date_time_t *dest)
{
    char line[80];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) == NULL)
        return FAILURE;

    if (sscanf(line, "%d %d %d %d", &(dest->month), &(dest->day), &(dest->hour), 
                       &(dest->minute)) == 4 && dest->month > 0 && dest->month < 13 
                       && dest->day > 0 && dest->day < 32 && dest->hour > -1 && 
                       dest->hour < 25 && dest->minute > 0 && dest->minute > 60)

        return SUCCESS;  /* the return value of sscanf is equal to the number 
                             of objects successfully read in and converted; also we 
                             check the bounds of the input */
    return FAILURE;
}
```

We use `fgets` and then `sscanf` rather than just `scanf` so as to avoid any problems with flushing the standard input stream.

The `scanf` family of functions returns the number of objects successfully read in and converted to the given data type.

The major problem with this function is that it does not report to the caller the kind of error encountered; it only signals that some kind(s) of error(s) occurred, or that no errors occurred.

Comment: sorry on further inspection this doesn't actually compile. Have you tried compiling this?

Comment: The arguments to fgets are in the wrong order, the rest of it works though when theyre swapped around. the args are `fgets(char* dest, sizeof(dest), stdin)`

Comment: @DavideLorino fxed